# linux/sysctl.h: no such file or directory when compiling TDengine in alpine

Tags: c, linux, tdengine

Alpine is a Linux distribution that I guess it must have the header files. How to solve it in alpine container?

Comment: "Alpine is a Linux distribution that I guess it must have the header files."
Guess again, the base alpine image is very minimal

Comment: You probably want to install https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/linux-headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linux-headers` should be installed exlicitly in alpine linux.

```sh
apk add linux-headers
```